# How to change item position of a recycle view from within its adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Is it possible to change the item from within the adapter itself?

What am I trying to a achieve?

I have created a simple recycler view and it has a simple list item, but when the user clicks on the item a bottom sheet dialog gets displayed (that bottom sheet is being created in the adapter itself so it's different for every item) that bottom sheet dialog have a back and next button which can allow the user to move back and forth through the item view

When the user clicks on item -> bottom sheet dialog gets displayed -> if he presses next I have to show next following item with its bottom sheet opened.

How can I move from I item to another within the adapter?

Comment: Hey you need to pass a current clicked item postion an your arraylist data as a parameter to bottomsheet dialog and when click on Next then close curent one bottomsheet if required and do same operation when click on list item, means open Bottomsheet dialog of and pass position + 1 so it's display next bottomsheet item!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who shared their ideas.
Here is what I finally did

1. created an interface within the adapter
2. implemented that interface in the fragment which was starting the adapter
3. when the user press the next or previous button, I dismiss the current bottom sheet and then I call the function in the interface and also pass it the position of either next to or previous item
4. When the implemented function gets called in the fragment, first I move the list to that position second i get the item on that positon and third call perform on click on that item and it displayed the bottom sheet of that item

here is the fun which get called in fragment

```
override fun onAddIconClick(position: Int) {
    surveyBinding.surveyRecV.scrollToPosition(position)
    val v: View? = surveyBinding.surveyRecV.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)
    if(v != null) {
        v.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.viewAddIcon).performClick()
        val temp = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.viewMainTitle)
        Log.i("here22" , temp.text.toString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass position and list item as ArrayList to bottom sheet and update UI on next and previous buttons.

for example, you can create a method in your bottom sheet to update bottom sheet UI:

```kotlin
    var listItem = ArrayList<Objects>()
    var position = 0
    
    private fun updateUi() {
        val item = listItem[position]
        ///update ui with item
    }
```

on next button click:

```kotlin
  position += 1
    if (position == listItem.size)
    {
        // end of list
    } else
    {
        updateUi()
    }
```

and on pervious button click:

```
    position -= 1
    if (position == -1)
    {
        // end of list
    } else
    {
        updateUi()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`RecyclerView` has a couple of convenience methods, [`scrollToPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#scrollToPosition(int)) and [`smoothScrollToPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#smoothScrollToPosition(int)) (the latter needs a little setup, check the link). You can use these to change the current item being displayed.

That requires having a reference to the `RecyclerView` though, which your `Adapter` doesn't have (or at least, it doesn't expose it). [There's a callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onAttachedToRecyclerView(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView)) when on starts observing the adapter though. So you could store that reference when you get it (but don't hold onto it when the equivalent `onDetached` callback happens)

---

Personally I'd want to separate all these things out, have them coordinated by the containing fragment, or some other component. So instead of one component (the adapter) managing what other components are doing and showing, it just calls a function saying "hey this item got clicked" and what happens as a result is none of its concern.

There's lots of ways to coordinate that, but it keeps things neater if you can separate that functionality. When one thing that has a specific job (displaying items and handling clicks) starts doing other stuff (messing with other UI components, handling stuff *they* do) it can start getting complex. Up to you but it's worth thinking about!